# Kong Gateway using Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes

Trying to deploy kong gateway via Kubernetes:

1. Created a namespace: **kong-helm**
2. Applied yaml files (using kubectl on kong-helm namespace) which includes: configmap.yaml, service.yaml, secret.yaml, ingress.yaml.
3. Upon applying the dbless.yaml(**https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Kong/kubernetes-ingress-controller/master/deploy/single/all-in-one-dbless.yaml**)ingress dbless pod is running.
4. `kubectl get svc --all-namespaces` - able to see the **service(kong-test-poc)** is created.

But when port forward is given: `kubectl port-forward service/kong-test-poc 80:8080`

**Getting the following error:** Error from server (NotFound): services "kong-test-poc" not found

Can you please tell how to rectify this error?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing the specific namespace where the service is running to it's going to your `default` namespace.

```
kubectl -n kong-helm port-forward service/kong-test-poc 8080:8080
```

I also recommend using an different port than 80 locally as this a unix reserved port. Also make sure that the `kong-test-poc` is configured to listen on `8080` (you didn't post the definition)

Comment: Tried this solution but getting timed out error.

Comment: I made some changes to the answer. Basically you don't typically use port 80 locally, and double check that `kong-test-poc` is configured listening on port `8080`